# Discord Bot Python add_roles

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot which gives you a "Member" role when you type `!join`.

I'm having problems with `add_roles`.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from webserver import keep_alive

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="OG")
    await member.add_roles(role)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("yeay eyea")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
  member = ctx.message.author
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
  await bot.add_roles(member, role)

keep_alive()
TOKEN = os.environ.get("NjQwMTQaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA4qHkx3Tl-l3CbpX8kTICfA")
bot.run("NaaaaaaaaaaaaaTICfA")
```

This is the error I get when I try to use the command `"!join"`:

```
Ignoring exception in command join:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext
/commands/core.py", line 79, in wrapped    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 23, in join
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError:'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

`add_roles` does not exist?

Comment: As the traceback says: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I'm making an answer instead of a comment, but I can't post comments due to my low rep. The error you're getting is because the co-routine is from a Member Class. So you need to do `member.add_roles(member, role)` instead of `bot.add_roles()`
EDIT: Also, make sure to remove/change your token, as it allows people to change your bots code and essentially hijack your bot.